# Python Pandas error: "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous." when engineering new feature with geopy library

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting a **"The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."** error whenever I run the code below.

I've read various answers on stackoverflow but nothing seems to point to the solution.

I have 2 coordinates: 1) a worker and 2) a job.

These exist in a pandas dataframe.

I want to use these 2 coordinates to engineer a distance to work feature using the geopy python library.

Here is the code:

```
try:
    df['distance_to_job'] = geopy.distance.geodesic(
        (df['wa_latitude'], df['wa_longitude']), 
        (df['worker_latitude'], df['worker_longitude'])).km
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
    df['distance_to_job'] = 0

df[['wa_latitude','wa_longitude','worker_latitude','worker_longitude','distance_to_job']].head(30)
```

All the longitude and latitude values are float64, however **there are some NaN values in there**.

Also, the following DID work (I tried it as a test):

```
df['distance_to_job'] = geopy.distance.vincenty(
    (47.384262, 8.574091), 
    (47.497915, 8.736907)
).km
```

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Just tried a suggestion based on the comments below. Got a different error. See below:
[image]

Comment: Can you try `df['distance_to_job'] = df[['wa_latitude','wa_longitude','worker_latitude','worker_longitude']].apply(lambda row: geopy.distance.geodesic(
        (row['wa_latitude'], row['wa_longitude']), 
        (row['worker_latitude'], row['worker_longitude'])).km, axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks @DOOM - I just tried it, but now getting a different error. See above - I edited my post.

Comment: The issue is you have `nan`'s in your data. So let's set them to `0` first. Place this before the try block, `df[['wa_latitude','wa_longitude','worker_latitude','worker_longitude']] = df[['wa_latitude','wa_longitude','worker_latitude','worker_longitude']].apply(lambda row: np.nan_to_num(row, 0.0), axis=1, result_type='broadcast')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem of last solution is need `try-except` for each row, so custom function is:

```
def f(row):
    try:
        return geopy.distance.geodesic((row['wa_latitude'], row['wa_longitude']), 
                                       (row['worker_latitude'], row['worker_longitude'])).km
     except:
         return 0

df['distance_to_job'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, your solution worked! But you need to change the 'x' (variable passed into the function) to 'row' (which is then used within the function).